# Git merge all but my untracked files

Tags: android, git, git-merge, git-pull

I'm working on a Git-versioned Android project with a team in my lab. One of the other members tells me he made major changes to the code, and wants me to pull them in. They're not in the upstream master yet, so I can't pull from that, so I've set his fork up as a remote, and want to pull from one of his branches.

My problem is that I am not tracking the bin folder in my copy of the project, as its entirely generated files and shouldn't be versioned. He however, does have the bin folder tracked, and when I try to pull his changes I get a message:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
>   by merge:

followed by a listing of all my bin folder files. How do I pull all of his files except for the bin folder? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the answer but you should put the bin folder in .gitignore. Your colleage would then get this file and stop put the generated files in version control.

Comment: I added the bin folder to my .gitignore, and that will be good down the road, once he gets that file, but until then I still really do need to pull his files. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: You can simply erases the file, merge, and then regenerate them in Eclipse before commiting, no ?

Comment: A somewhat cheap solution may be to rename your bin folder, pull his updates, delete his bin folder, and move yours back in its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion :

- put the bin folder in .gitignore so that your colleage would stop put the generated files in version control
- remove the bin folder in your work directory and then merge (pull) his change
- erase his bin folder
- regenerate the bin folder in Eclipse, commit and send (along with the .gitignore)